# How to change a number to be divisible by 8

Tags: c, numbers

could you tell me how to generate a smallest number greater to an input one which is divisible by 8? (preferable in C)

Is there a general solution for powers of two?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest number greater or equal to input which is divisible by 8:

```
return (input + 7) & ~7;
```

The smallest number greater  than input which is divisible by 8:

```
return (input + 8) & ~7;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
static inline int round_up_to_multiple_of_8 (int v)
{
   return (v|7)+1;
}
```

This works because 8 is a power of two, so setting the 3 lowest bits gives the number below the next multiple of 8.

Comment: But this will not be greater than the input...

Comment: I'm looking for a number greater than an input one... Thanks for reply anyway

Answer (score 0):

r= x mod 8;
x+r is your answer

Comment: Too slow... I'd also like to make it less or equal

Comment: It is slow when you don't enable compiler optimizations. An optimizing compiler would optimize that to bit-or.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would do this by:

```
int roundUp(int input, int round)
{
    return input + round - (input % round);
}
```

However for the case of 8, the other solutions will usually run faster.